# Different Title for Product view pages and other pages

Tags: magento-1.9, page-title

I need to have output in a way that all the other pages should get the default title but for product detail page I need a specific title.For this so far I tried adding this code

```
<h3><?php echo $this->getLayout()->getBlock('head')->getTitle();?></h3>-->>This is for common title
<?php if(Mage::registry('current_product')) ?>
<h3><?php echo "Feaured Products";?></h3>-->>this if for product detail page title.
<?php endif; ?>
```

but doing in this way crashing my page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot a semicolon.

```
<?php if(Mage::registry('current_product')) ?>
```

should be

```
<?php if(Mage::registry('current_product')) : ?>
```

When developing, turn the error reporting on and the developer mode. This way you get a clear message of what's wrong with your code.

Comment: Thank you for the answer and also for your suggestion @marius